# Проблемы с кодировкой при отправке html-шаблона с русским текстом: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, windows-10, flask

Дано: Windows 10, Python 3.4, PyScripter, Flask
Есть файл (допустим `main.py`) в котором вызывается шаблон

```
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

в `index.html` поле для ввода

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
```

Если так запустить `localhost:5000` то все ок, но если изменить на русский язык

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName">Имя</label>
```

то выдает ошибку

> builtins.UnicodeDecodeError
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 437: >invalid continuation byte

Python3 по умолчанию использует кодировку `utf-8`, в файле `html` также
`meta charset="utf-8"` прописано.
Traceback начинает ругаться на строчку
`return render_template('index.html')` в `main.py`.

Comment: Недостаточно прописать meta utf-8, нужно ещё сам файл сохранить именно в кодировке utf-8

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! помогло :)

Comment: @andreymal, может, опубликуете комментарий в качестве ответа? Вопрос-то про не просто опечатку, а куда более сложное и коварное явление.

Comment: @Arhad нуок . .

Answer (score 5):

Недостаточно прописать `<meta charset="utf-8" />`, нужно ещё сам файл сохранить именно в кодировке utf-8.

---

Зачем?

Прописанная мета никак не влияет на содержимое файла. Она лишь даёт подсказку браузеру, какую кодировку использовать для декодирования файла. Можно написать мету cp1251, а сохранить всё равно в utf-8 — это будет работать, только в браузере будут кракозябры, потому что он послушается подсказку и попытается раскодировать utf-8 байты как cp1251 символы.

Flask не использует мету. Он (точнее, Jinja2) тупо читает текстовый файл и интерпретирует его как шаблон Jinja2. А HTML ли там, или CSS, или JS, или JSON — фласку пофиг.

Шаблонизатор Jinja2 по умолчанию [пытается прочитать файлы как utf-8](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/bbe0a4174c2846487bef4328b309fddd8638da39/jinja2/loaders.py#L160-L175), и ему плевать на ваши меты.

---

Но это ещё не всё: вся обработка шаблона завязана на юникодных строках <sub>(у которых для простоты можно считать, что они не имеют конкретной кодировки, так как это деталь реализации питона, для нас не важная)</sub>, и `render_template` возвращает юникодную (не байтовую!) строку независимо от того, в какой кодировке был сохранён файл и что там понаписано в метах.

Перед отправкой ответа браузера Flask должен обратно закодировать юникодную строку в какие-то байты, и [по умолчанию для этого используется кодировка utf-8](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L784).

Таким образом неважно, в какой кодировке сохранён файл и что написано в мете — браузеру будут отправлены всегда utf-8 байты! Браузер будет пытаться раскодировать эти байты согласно подсказке, прописанной в мете. То есть если вы замените кодировку по умолчанию в Jinja2 (и при этом не замените в Flask Response), то кодировка исходного файла-шаблона и кодировка, прописанная в мете, вообще не обязаны совпадать :)

---

Кодировки Python-файлов и кодировки по умолчанию в самом Python в данном конкретном случае не играют никакой роли.

Comment: Может добавить что браузер при скачивании страницы скачивает не текст, а байты, к которым еще нужно будет раскодировать?

Comment: @gil9red ой, тогда ещё надо будет вспомнить, что фласк при отправке ответа закодирует юникодные строки в utf-8)

Comment: Что-то там добавил, но как-то сумбурненько получилось)